# Wireshark Traffic Analysis for File type

Tags: networking, wireshark, pcap

So I am wondering how can we utilize Wireshark to see if a users has downloaded a txt file over the internet.

I tried this while running wireshark:
https://code.google.com/p/androidnetworktester/downloads/detail?name=1mb.txt

I followed the HTTP stream, and can see the URL and a bunch, but in the PCAP packet body, I can't find the 1mb.txt file anywhere. Just curious, if we are doing forensics works, how can we prove the person really downloaded this using this wireshark information? Is it because it's using SSL that all the text in the PCAP is scattered with random code?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if we are doing forensics works, how can we prove the person really downloaded this using this wireshark information

You can't really prove it from the packet capture unless you are able to decode the content. In most cases this is not possible, but if you have access to the private key of the site (you usually don't because it is private) and if RSA key exchange was used then you can decode the traffic after capture.

What you can get from the packet capture is the target host of the request, but not the exact URL or even the content. But if the length of the packet capture  matches about the length of the content (there is some overhead in transport) and if you know that this is the only file at the server of this size than you might have at least an indicator that the user might have downloaded this file. But is probably not enough as a real prove.
For more prove you might then have a look at this history of the browser.

Comment: Thank you I am thinking the same thing. For HTTP it's pretty straight forward. The URL is not hidden, for SSL maybe we need to decrpt as you mentioned, using the priviate key. Just wonder if we have anything else we can use the PCAP for. Thank you.